Update Dock app icon cache without killall-ing it
I have a sheel script that changes the icon of an app by modifying the .../Contents/Resources/app.icns file, then touch /Applications/App.app so that the change is visible in the Finder.
But for this to be visible in the Dock, I also need to command-click on the icon in the Dock.
Is there a way of automating this trick and avoid having to killall Dock? (I always have minimized windows and I don't want them all to reappear.)
